# How to display search results table after a minimum of characters has been typed?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a UITableViewController that displays a list of products with a search bar.

I would like to display the table of results only when the user has typed a minimum of 3 characters (in the search bar). Until this limit, I would like the table displayed be still the complete list of products.

The method `- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController` (where I made my query) is

> Called when the search bar becomes the first responder or
>   when the user makes changes inside the search bar. (required)

So I thought of running my "if statement" in this method (`if (searchText.length > 3)` etc.. ) but that does not behave as I would like to. (When I type a search text which length < 3 I see an empty results table.)

I think I should rather delay the call of the  `- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController` until the search text is 3 characters but I don't know how can I do that and if my idea is correct.

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Write your reloading new data code after the if statement

```
(if (searchText.length > 3){
 //Load new or whatever data in the array that populates your tableview.
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use UIPopoverController and pass sarch array in tableview which are exist in it follow this link it may help

http://www.raywenderlich.com/29472/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uipopovercontroller-tutorial